# How to bind a path variable to the request body parameter?

Tags: postman

I want to post a HTTP request like this:

http://localhost/context/{{name}}/{{age}}

And I want to bind these path variables to request body, if my request body is :

```
{
  "name": "Frank",
  "age": 18
}
```

the final request I want to send is:

http://localhost/context/Frank/18

so how to achieve this function in POSTMAN?

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSkPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning your request in Postman (non-parametric url):

[image]

Parametric url:

[image]

I don't think you need to pass variables in your route, since you're already passing them in the request-body. However, here's a brief.

If you're working with NodeJS (using Express) and any JS library, you can send the request as thus, (using axios):

```
const body = {
  "name": "Frank",
  "age": 18
}
const requestHandler = async() => {
    const serverResponse = await axios.post(`http://localhost/context/${body.name}/${body.age}`, {data: body}, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${backend-token}`
    }
};
```

Then, on your server-side, with a proper definition for your routes (for parametric and non-parametric choice of url), you'd create a route to handle the request as:

**Using Express**

```
import {Router} from "express";
const yourServerRouter = Router();
yourServerRouter.post(`yourPrimaryDomain/:name/:age`, function-to-handle-request)
```

If you're working with a python framework (Flask or Django), you can do thus:

**Flask** (using flask_restful):

```
urls = [f"your_base_url/name/age"]
from flask_restful import Resource, request
import json

class BioData(Resource):
    def post(self):
        url = request.url
        if "context" in url:
            request_body = json.loads(request.data)
            response = self.context_handler(request_data)

    def context_handler(self, request_data):
         name, age = request_data
         ....
         ....
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.add_resource(BioData, *urls)
```

**Django** (Using DRF - viewsets)

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers

class BioDataViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSets):
    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False, url_name="context", url_path="context")
    def context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        clients_request = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

Define your path as above (for flask):

```
context_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
context_router.register("name/age/", company_viewsets.CompanyViewSets)
url_patterns = [path(f"your_base_url/context", include(context_router.urls())]
```

Comment: The demo I provided above may not be appropriate. Actually, I want to  forward the request with the path parameter.
Also, I want to implement dynamic parameter binding in `POSTMAN` rather than through code.@Chukwunazaekpere

Comment: @Frank What framework are you using?

Comment: Spring, but it's not about the framework. I want to post this kind of request in POSTMAN, which can automatic parse the request body and filling specific parameters in the request body into the url.@Chukwunazaekpere

Comment: Every framework has its method of capturing parametres in url; like I illustrated in the examples above. If that isn't followed, you'll get a 404. See the second picture as well.

Comment: My description may have misunderstood you, actually what I want is already added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got some clues from this [page](https://community.postman.com/t/how-can-i-read-the-content-of-a-form-data-request-body-variable-in-the-test-script/15711). The request body can be parsed through `Pre-request-Script`, and the attributes of interest can be set as variables and referenced in URL.

```
var r = JSON.parse(request.data);
pm.variables.set("name", r.name);
pm.variables.set("age", r.age);
```

And use below form to apply variables set in the `Pre-request-Script`:

```
http://localhost/context/{{name}}/{{age}}
```

the request body is :

```
{
  "name": "Frank",
  "age": 18
}
```

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXfxz.png)